# Make list of from two lists, element-by-element, using logical comparisons

Tags: python, list, comparison, logic

Is there a function that will take two lists, perform some logical comparison element-by-element, then create a list based on those comparisons?

Example:

```
>>> x = [4, 6, 2, 4]
>>> y = [8, 4, 1, 5]

>>> z = magicalfunction(x, y, logical_comparison='greatest element')
>>> print(z)
[8, 6, 2, 5]
```

Comment: Try **map**?  It's in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map` with `max`:

```
>>> x = [4, 6, 2, 4]
>>> y = [8, 4, 1, 5]
>>> map(max, x, y)
[8, 6, 2, 5]
```

You should call `list` on the output in Python 3

Comment: @nevabyte The function to map can be changed

Comment: @MosesKoledoye If I remember map correctly, I should be able to replace max with a lambda which would then be able to do different logical comparisons?

Comment: @u2berggeist Yes, certainly

Answer (score 1):

This should work too

```
>>> x = [4, 6, 2, 4]
>>> y = [8, 4, 1, 5]
>>> [x[i] if x[i]> y[i] else y[i] for i in range(len(x))]
[8, 6, 2, 5]
>>> [xi if xi> yi else yi for i in zip(x, y)]
# or this way as suggested by u2berggeist
```

Comment: Ah, good old list comprehensions... Also, the more pythonic way would be `[xi if xi>yi else yi for xi, yi in zip(x,y)]` Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No there's actually no such function, but with `map` (or list-comprehensions) you can at least simulate some possible "logical operations":

```
def magicalfunction(x, y, logical_comparison):
    if logical_comparison == 'greatest element':
        func = max
    elif logical_comparison == 'smallest element':
        func = min
    elif logical_comparison == 'shortest element':
        # Just as example of a custom function / logical comparison
        def func(xi, yi):
            if len(yi) > len(xi):
                return xi
            else:
                return yi
        # or "func = functools.partial(min, key=len)"
    else:
        raise ValueError('unknown operation')
    return list(map(func, x, y))
```

Depending on your use-case you might need to check which logical operations you want to support and add more `elif`s there.

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy.where()` see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for more information;

```
import numpy as np
logical = np.where(np.array(x) > y, x, y)
```

With `where` you can use any logical operator such as below;

```
logical = np.where(np.array(x) | y, x, y)
logical = np.where(np.array(x) & y, x, y)
logical = np.where(np.array(x) >> y, x, y)
```

Comment: This produces `array([8, 4, 1, 5])`. Why didn't you stick with `np.maximum(x, y)`?

Comment: @Rawing because the OP asked for any logical comparison, `np.maximum` doesn't accommodate for that. Changing to `>` should fix that.

Comment: You need at least one of the arguments to be an `np.array`: `np.where(np.array(x) >= y, x, y)`, otherwise `x >= y` is done in plain Python which returns a single boolean, not array of booleans